# Change color of the dropdown text and add <optgroup> tag based on text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown populating from database with following text.

Item1
Item2* 
Item3*
Item4

I want to change the color of the item2 & item3 to red (based on * symbol), item1 and item4 to green. Also group them as group1 and group2.

### Result

Group1
  Item1
  Item4
Group2
  item2*
  item3*

How can I achieve this using jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can not you select items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the `*` and wrap them in `<optgroup>`, then wrap the rest

```js
var $sel = $('#mySelect'),
  $starGroup = $('<optgroup label="Group 2" class="red-group">');

$sel.children().filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf('*') > -1;
}).appendTo($starGroup);

$sel.children().wrapAll('<optgroup label="Group 1" class="green-group">');

$sel.append($starGroup);
```

```css
.red-group option {
  color: red
}
.green-group option {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" size=6>
  <option value="">item 1</option>
  <option value="">item 2*</option>
  <option value="">item 3*</option>
  <option value="">item 4</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: to remove `*` modify the filter part to

```
$sel.children().filter(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text(),
      hasStar = txt.indexOf('*') > -1;
      if(hasStar){
         $(this).text(txt.replace('*',''))
      }
  return hasStar;
}).appendTo($starGroup);
```

Comment: How can I remove * after all operation is done from dropdown?

Comment: can do it inside the filter...check it first, then modify it

Comment: $sel.children().filter(function() {
                        if($(this).text().indexOf('*') > -1){                            
                            return $(this).text().replace('*','');     
                        }                        
                    }).appendTo($starGroup); This code not doing anything. Can you please help.

Comment: try edit i made. Also feel free to accept answer as it did what was originally asked